# Cron job python Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to add a scheduled task to fetch a URL via cron job using google app engine. I am continuously getting a failure. I am just fetching www.google.com. Why is the url fetch failing? Am I missing something?

Comment: GAE cron jobs just access urls from your application at specified intervals. If the url you're giving to the cron job doesn't work when you access it manually, it's not going to work when cron hits it. Can you post the code for the handler you're trying to run?

Comment: We need more details. What's the contents of your app.yaml and cron.yaml? What's in the cron handler? And what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

"fetch" your OWN url (on appspot.com probably, but, who cares -- use a relative url anywau1-), not `google.com`, the homepage of the search engine -- what's that got to do w/your app anyway?!-)...

Comment: @Ambreen, so please post the details of your code and error messages / logs / etc, it's absolutely impossible to debug your problem without more information!